# is "I am free since tomorrow" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Are there better forms for that sentence? "I am free starting from tomorrow" . Also, do suggest the conditions under which I can use 'since'. Thanks!

Comment: Starting tomorrow, I am free.

Comment: "Since" is never used in the future (except occasionally in the future perfect, which is a kind of past-in-the-fouture).

Comment: @Colin is that a rule you read in a book or is it something you are saying from observation? let me know! thanks

Answer (score 4):

Close.  The common, idiomatic expression would be "I am free **after** tomorrow".

"I am free **from** tomorrow" is also acceptable, but this implies a **to**, after which you will not be free.

> I am free *from* next week (*until* the end of the month).
>
> I am free *from* Saturday (*to* Monday).

Yes, these time frames are ambiguous.  If you want precision you would have to ask for more detail.

Comment: What can you say about, "**Starting tomorrow, I am free**"?

Comment: @SovereignSun  yes, that's also fine, as well as a number of other ways. "As of tomorrow evening I will be free ..." etc.

Comment: Fo me, "I am free from tomorrow" does not imply a "to": it is quite acceptable without.

Comment: i didnt know from could be used like that. is there really a time-frame for 'from'? couldn't from also imply an indefinite period of time for which i am free?

Comment: @Lipsa it *implies* a "to" but you can leave it unspecified